# Transforming table with aggregation over rows and new column creation

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I am to new to post table views, so I will try to explain how my data looks:
I have the customer id, order id, the sales date, the product bought and also the price of the product. We sell 3 Products: K, N and E. Every row shows the product the customer bought and it's price. Customers can buy in the same order the same product several times, but also buy other products. Below I am trying to aggregate the prices per product, so that in the end I will have one column per customer and order and new price columns created.

Currently writing CTEs:

```sql
with N as (select Customer_ID, Order_ID, Sales_Date,
       sum(Price)
from orders
group by 1,2,3
where product = 'N'),
K as (select Customer_ID, Order_ID, Sales_Date,
       sum(Price)
from orders
group by 1,2,3
where product = 'K'),
E as (select Customer_ID, Order_ID, Sales_Date,
       sum(Price)
from orders
group by 1,2,3
where product = 'E')
select N.*,
K.Price as K_Price,
E.Price as E_Price
from N as N
left join K as K on K.Customer_ID=N.Customer_ID
left join E as E on E.Customer_ID=N.Customer_ID
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? If product options increase from 3 to 20 - I will have 20 CTEs, maybe it's better to write the query in a different way?

Comment: Don't *explain* what data looks like.  Include sample data and desired results.  A clear explanation of what you want to do would also help.  I assume that you mean one *row* per customer with a separate column for each price.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select Customer_ID, Order_ID, Sales_Date,
       sum(price) filter (where product = 'N') as n_price,
       sum(price) filter (where product = 'K') as k_price,
       sum(price) filter (where product = 'E') as e_price
from orders o
group by Customer_ID, Order_ID, Sales_Date;
```